# Javascript async parallel - How to return the final result/callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

How to return the final result/callback to the calling function?
All examples in the documentation only show console.log() options.

The following code is just for example purposes.

```
function foo(input) {
    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            callback(null, input.one);
        },
        function(callback) {
            callback(null, input.two);
        }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
        // What to do here? all examples include console.log()
        // I want to return the result ([1, 2]) to the calling function!
    });
}

var data = {"one": 1, "two": 2};
var bar = foo(data);

console.log(bar); // Will return [1, 2]
```

Edit: This question was marked as duplicate. The other post did not explain how this was done to someone with marginal experience with javascript and callbacks.

Comment: Add callback to your `foo` function and call it with the result from the final `async` callback.

Comment: Why are you using `async` if your two functions are not actually asynchronous?

Comment: @alexmac could you please post the answer? I`m still trying to wrap my head around callbacks :|

Comment: @bergi It is just an example. I`m trying to learn :)

Answer (score 2):

If your function contains async code so it becomes an async function. You need to include a callback :

```
    function foo(input, cb) {

       async.parallel([
          function(callback) {
              callback(null, input.one);
          },
          function(callback) {
            callback(null, input.two);
          }
      ],
      function(err, results) {
       return cb(results);
      });
   }
```

And modify your call :

```
var data = {"one": 1, "two": 2};
foo(data, function(bar){
  console.log(bar);

});
```

Comment: Don't ignore the error! Just use `async.parallel([…], cb)` directly.

Comment: @DanielBjørnådal `return` statement is not required there.